# Making display:inline behaves like display:inline-block

Tags: html, css

I'm making a form with two input area, the second area should be content editable div somehow.

I want to make the `#topic_title_input` sitting  above the `#topic_content_input` with the same width. It could be easily achieved by giving them `display:inline-block`,  But for some complicated reason, I can't change the `display-inline` property of the second input area

Any idea how to make the `#topic_title_input` sitting above the `#topic_content_input`?

html

```
 <div class="left_container">
    <input id="topic_title_input" >
    <div id="topic_content_input" contenteditable="true" ></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right_container">
    </div>
    <div class="clear_float">
    </div>
```

css

```
 #topic_title_input{
    width:521px;

}


#topic_content_input{

/*do not change the display:inline */
width:521px;
display:inline; 
background-color: orange;
border: solid 1px black;
}

/*do not change the css below*/
.left_container{

    position:relative; 
    float:left; width:50%;
}
.right_container{

    position:relative; 
    float:right; width:50%;
}

</style>
```

Comment: second input area? What do you mean by that? Do you want the `div` to be floated to the right next to the `input` ?

Comment: I mean the content editable div

Comment: What if you add this: `#topic_title_input{display:block;}` and to your content this: `#topic_content_input{float:left;}` would that help?

Comment: Thanks, it works, however, for that cross-browsing issue I can't use float property either. Any other ideas?

Comment: @问题大王 What issue with float property? Are you aiming to prehistorical browsers or something?

Comment: The only thing that could happen is that within older IE versions you will see odd floating effect. In that case you need to add a clear panel to your code after the floating objects @问题大王

Comment: It is the safari, if content editable div with height:100px and display:inline-bock or float, it creates a giant I-beam cursor when clicked.